# Laravel Table Joining

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have three tables .

**users**

```
id name
```

**roles**

```
id name
```

**role_user**

```
id user_id role_id
```

I want to join them like

```
id name name(role) user_id role_id
```

My vision is to show the role name of the user.

I have tried this :

```
DB::table('users')
            ->join('role_user', 'users.id', '=', 'role_user.user_id')
            ->join('roles', 'role_user.role_id', '=', 'roles.id')
            ->select('users.id', 'role_user.role_id', 'roles.name')
            ->get();
```

Can you please tell me what I am doing wrong or if I am going thru a bad way.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name field is "double". This is not a problem for your database but it will not display well. Try the following code:

```
$result = DB::table('..etc.')->get(['users.*','role_user.role_id','roles.name as role_name']);
foreach($result as $row) {
    print_r($row->toArray());
}
```

As you can see I've changed the get() call to make sure that the user's "name" field does not clash with the role's "name" field.

Comment: This returns nothing. I replaced your ...etc. to users

Comment: Include your entire query. All you should need to change is the parameter of get()